# Change UIButton border when it's disabled

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to hide the border of a button when it's disabled. When it's enabled, I set the border like this:

```
_btnInit.layer.borderWidth = 1;
_btnInit.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor]CGColor];
```

And when it's disabled, I want to delete the border.
[image]

Like in the picture. The left is in the disabled state and the right is at the normal state.

Comment: just change `btnInit.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor]CGColor];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Swift just go with what 'PPL's answer, if you want it in objective-c it is very similar:

1) Create a UIButton subclass like:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BorderedDisabledButton : UIButton

@end
```

2) Override `setEnabled` property in the `.m` file

```
- (void)setEnabled:(BOOL)enabled {
    [super setEnabled:enabled];

    if (enabled) {
        self.layer.borderWidth = 0.0;
    } else {
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Subclass UIButton and override isEnabled property like this,

```
override var isEnabled: Bool {
    didSet {
        if isEnabled {
            self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
            self.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
        } else {
            self.layer.borderWidth = 0.0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change border based on condition if button is enable or disable and set your button border like as follow:

```
if ([btnInit isEnabled]) {
  _btnInit.layer.borderWidth = 1;
  _btnInit.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor]CGColor];
} else {
  _btnInit.layer.borderWidth = 0;
  _btnInit.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**For Enable**

```
_btnInit.layer.borderWidth = 1;
_btnInit.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor grayColor]CGColor];
```

**For Disable**

```
_btnInit.layer.borderWidth = 0;
_btnInit.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor]CGColor];
```